# Excel Extracting Specific Words From 1 Column to Another

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to parse column A to get specific names to populate column B. As some of the information is automatically generated, I used =TRIM to pull the words that follow after certain characters to get the desired result.

Ex: "(DROP FAIL) Acer" in column A shows up as just "Acer" in column B.

The problem is the data that doesn't follow this standard:

Ex: "DROP FAIL - Acer" displays as "#VALUE!" in column B.

There are a lot of names that have this issue. Is there anyway around this?

Comment: How many other variations are there? You could use some nested [IFERROR function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/IFERROR-function-F59BACDC-78BD-4924-91DF-A869D0B08CD5)s to pass processing to the next if one fails.

Comment: This question seems quite incomplete. Can you please share the full formula you are using? `=TRIM("(DROP FAIL) Acer")` should just produce "(DROP FAIL) Acer". Not sure how you are seeing that it only produces "Acer". Don't think it is the source of your `#VALUE` error either. Can you run through the "Evaluate Formula" wizard?

Comment: Column A is a description of an order: "(DROP FAIL) Acer {no record found}" this is where I use =TRIM(MID(A2,C2,D2-C2))
Column B is the company name: "Acer"
Column C is a =FIND(")",A2)+1 forumla to find where the parenthesis end
Column D is a =FIND("{",A2,C2) formula to find where the curly brackets start.

The middle part, it the order was automated, contains the company name.

But if the order was manual, it doesn't always look like that. I'm looking for a way to pull the company names from the manual ones too.

Answer (score 1):

You can nest a series of [IFERROR](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/IFERROR-function-F59BACDC-78BD-4924-91DF-A869D0B08CD5) functions that pass processing onto the next when an error is encountered.

```
=TRIM(REPLACE(A2, 1, IFERROR(FIND(")", A2), FIND("-", A2)), TEXT(,)))
```

[image: nested_replace]

Comment: A very clever approach !